# ML.NET Features Metrics is 1 or 0

Tags: ml.net

I am using ML.NET prediction and return prediction, score and features metrics. Features are 1 or 0. What is the meaning of that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have some confusion on the terminology, but it sounds like this is a binary classification model.

- The "features" are your input variables, the data your model will use to either train or generate predictions. For my cat example below, a feature might be a column like "AmountOfColourPurple=0.20"
- I think you are confusing that with "labels", which is the thing you are predicting, in this case 1/0 or true/false

For example if its a model predicting if a picture of something is a cat, it will return the label of 1 to say "yes this is a cat" or 0 for "no this is not a cat", the prediction score is the resulting confidence in its answer as a percentage.

Comment: No It's not label and I am not using binary classification. It's available as output.

Comment: Ill need more detail then, I am not sure what you mean by "What is the meaning of that?", what are you asking the meaning of? Do you have a response object I can see if its about the prediction response? Are you by chance asking about one of your features columns which literally have the values of "1" or "0"?